# How to start Apache Storm UI from Java code?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I develop a stream processing project with Storm. I created a topology and run it by executing the `Main` class of my project.

In Storm tutorials, I saw a UI that is accessed from `8080` port and it shows detailed information for spouts and bolts. But, I couldn't find a way to start the UI. How can I do that?

---

`pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Main class:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("TwitchSpout", new TwitchSpout());
builder.setBolt("MessageBolt", new MessageBolt()).shuffleGrouping("TwitchSpout");

Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(false);

new LocalCluster().submitTopology("MyFirstTopo", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

The UI that I want to start:
[image: UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your topology as a local cluster, which is just intended for testing. You should run it on a real cluster instead (see https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html).

Once you've set it up, you can start Storm UI with the command `storm ui` using the `storm.sh` script in `storm/bin`. There is currently not a way to start Storm UI in a LocalCluster.